# How to define method to act as decorator for other methods inside the same class in Python?

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators

I'm building simple JSON DB which has methods like `insert`, `update` , `get` and so on.

I know it's simple to create `self._write()` method to write to json file and call it in every method, but is there any way to create `_write` to be decorator on all these function, **but as method of a `Database` class** ?

I tried this, but I didn't managed to wrap my hand around it:

```
import pathlib
import json

DATABASE_PATH = pathlib.Path('/home/me/db.json')


class Database:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def _write(self):
        def decorator(f, *args, **kwargs):
            _response = f(**kwargs)  # I'm assuming this would be `insert` method call ?
            with DATABASE_PATH.open(mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as _db:
                json.dump(self.data, _db, indent=4)  # Calling `f` would modify `self.data`
            return _response

        return decorator

    @_write  # Complaining function `_write` lacks positional argument self, but can't access it ?
    def insert(self, **kwargs):
        if all(k for k in kwargs if k in ('name', 'surname')):  # Insert if contains all values.
            self.data.update(**kwargs)
            return True
        return False  # Insert failed.
```

Is it possible to write class method to act as a decorator which will be used on other class methods defined in the same class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to wrap my head around this problem, but at the end I simply choose to extract `_write` out class to as regular decorator function.

This solution breaks many rules of *The Zen of Python*, if there's better solution I'll accept it:

```
import pathlib
import json

DATABASE_PATH = pathlib.Path('db.json')


class Database:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def _write(fn):
        def decorator(self, **kwargs):
            _response = fn(self, **kwargs)
            with DATABASE_PATH.open(mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as _db:
                json.dump(self.data, _db, indent=4)
            return _response
        return decorator

    @_write
    def insert(self, **kwargs):
        if all(k for k in kwargs if k in ('name', 'surname')):  # Insert if contains all values.
            self.data.update(**kwargs)
            return True
        return False  # Insert failed.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database()
    db.insert(name='Dummy-Name', surname='Dummy-Surname')
```